# I don't know how to make this if statement work

Tags: if-statement

this is the question on the homework: "If the person works, in hours per week, less than or equal to the number of hours in a normal work week, then the income is simply the payrate times hoursWorkedPerWeek."

this is the code i have, it says it's an unreachable statement:

```
public double getGrossIncome() {
    double income = 0;

    return income;

    if(hoursWorkedPerWeek <= NORMAL_WORK_WEEK){
        income = payRate * hoursWorkedPerWeek;
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you know what the `return` statement does?

Comment: Remember: order matters. The function will "exit" after it returns. Everything after that doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statements which are written after the return statement are never executed. Hence all these statements are termed unreachable statements.
We can have multiple return statements inside a method based on certain conditions.

For eg: In this method we have 2 return statements based on certain criteria.

```
  public String process(int x){
    if (x<18){
      return "Not eligible";
      //Not reachable area
    }
    else{
      return "eligible";
      //Not reachable area
    }
  }
```